# Unable to deploy to recreated deleted app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I deleted an app service from resource group and recreated in the different resource group with the same name, but not able to deploy through TFS-CD(azure app service deploy)

**EDIT**
This is sorted, there was no problem with the TFS -CD rather the app needed to be stopped before deploying.

Comment: You need to provide significantly more detail if you want help. You say *not able to deploy*. What does that mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what error message? Your question is currently equivalent to going to the doctor and saying "I don't feel good, what could be the problem?"

Comment: This is sorted, there was no problem with the TFS -CD rather the app needed to be stopped before deploying. @DanielMann noted!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same deployment profile you will fail. The App Service TestAppService when deleted and recreated to TestAppService gets a new ID.
The publish profile created in Visual Studio only works for one user and one machine. The machine name is not the identifying ID of the machine.

Simply create a new Publish Profile to the new machine.

You can delete publish profiles to deleted machines as they cannot be useful anymore.